# How do I submit a twitter-like micropost and show the post without reloading the page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to submit a micropost and have it show at the top of the page without having the page reload, but I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work.  Any explanations and solutions will be much appreciated.

I have a user with many microposts

**SOLUTION**

```
https://github.com/sunwooz/fasttwitter/pull/1

Here is a working implementation let me go thru the changes really quick

fasttwitter/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
Since rails 3.1 you should use "application" instead of "defaults" apparently this was the main       problem, because it generated an error stopped the remote => true from working
fasttwitter/app/views/microposts/create.js.coffee
There is no need for this file. rails is going to check for a .erb file not a .coffee
fasttwitter/app/views/microposts/create.js.erb
I had some problems with the partial rendering, but it is working with the html you posted on     Stackoverflow
```

and this is the **show.html.erb(user)**

```
<h1><%= @user.email %></h1>

<%= form_for [@user, @micropost], :remote => true do |f| %>
<h1>What are you thinking?</h1><br/>
<%= f.text_field :content, :class => 'micropostfield', :placeholder => 'Press ENTER to submit' %><br/>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<div id="microposts">
<%= render @user.microposts.reverse %>
</div>
```

**_micropost.html.erb partial**

```
<%= div_for micropost do %>
<h3><%= micropost.user.email %></h2> <h4>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago</h3>
<p>
    <%= micropost.content %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_micropost_path(micropost) %>
    <%= link_to "Destroy", user_micropost_path(micropost), :method => :delete, :class => :destroy %>
</p>
```

**Microposts.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#new_micropost').submit(function(evt){
    var text = $('#micropost_content').val();
    var url = $('#new_micropost').attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { micropost: { content: text }},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){
            $('#microposts').prepend('<div class="micropost"><h3>' + data.@user.email + '</h3><h4>Posted On: ' + data.created_at + '</h4><p>' + data.content + '</p></div>');
        };
    });
    evt.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Micropost create action

```
def create
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@micropost = @user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
respond_to do |format|
  if @micropost.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
    format.xml { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
    format.xml { render :xml => @micropost.errors }
    format.js { render :json => @micropost.errors }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to add the following

A javascript response on your `create` action of your controller action in case you don't have it. It can be as simple as

```
respond_to { |format| format.js }
```

Also be sure keep the `:remote  => true` on your form.

By adding a respond_to `js` your controller will try to find a file located under `app/views/model_plural/create.js.erb`.

`js.erb` files are just as an `html.erb` but you can embed Ruby into JS instead of embedding Ruby into HTML.

Now you can create your js views something like this one.

app/views/microposts/create.js.erb

```
<% if @micropost.errors.any? %>
  alert('errors');
<% else %>
    $('#microposts').prepend('<div class="micropost"><h3>' +  "<%= j @micropost.user.email%>" + '</h3><h4>Posted On: ' + "<%= j @micropost.created_at %>" + '</h4><p>' +  "<%= j @micropost.content %>" + '</p></div>');
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: To start off, thanks a lot for helping me out! I created the javascript file create.js.erb and i put a respond_to format.js line in the create action of the micropost controller.  I have the form set on :Remote => true but now it's reloading the page and submitting the micropost.  Do I have to get rid of the micropost partial and the old microposts.js file?

Comment: Don't know if you need to delete the js file but definitely you wont need it any more. You created the `js.erb` file on app/views/microposts/create.js.erb?..... Hey actually another question, what controller is actually handling the post request on your app(Userr or Microposts)?

Comment: Yeah create.js.erb in the microposts view.  I posted the micropost controller/create action.

Comment: [Here is the github](https://github.com/sunwooz/fasttwitter/tree/master/fasttwitter)

Comment: I've sent you a pull request, check it out

Comment: I love you so much, is there a hug button somewhere?

Comment: Btw, If I want to add a <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_micropost(@micropost) %> to the javascript how do I do it?  It breaks every time I try to add the links to the create.js.erb file.

Comment: It is important that you use the `escape_javascript` method, or the `j` method which is the same... check doc [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html)